# Process elements in futures::stream::Stream in parallel and simultaneously append new elements

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am trying to "connect" to multiple peers and "process" them in parallel. I have the following implementation

```rust
pub async fn process(addr: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
    println!("processed {}", addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut peers = vec!["127.0.0.1", "139.48.123.146", "123.123.46.209"];
    
    let conn_fut = futures::future::join_all(peers.iter().map(|peer| {
        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    }));
    
    // awaits all futures in parallell
    conn_fut.await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89eb355c6b7e16491b4b2c665a4a65b7)

output:

```
connecting to 127.0.0.1
connecting to 139.48.123.146
connecting to 123.123.46.209
processed 127.0.0.1
processed 139.48.123.146
processed 123.123.46.209
```

This is done in parallel since connecting to e.g. `139.48.123.146` can be done before processing `127.0.0.1`.

In addition to this I want to add new connections to `conn_fut` while I am awaiting all futures in parallel. I think something like this would work:

```rust
pub async fn process(addr: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
    println!("processed {}", addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["127.0.0.1", "139.48.123.146", "123.123.46.209"];

    let conn_fut = futures::future::join_all(peers.iter().map(|peer| {
        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    }));
    
    let new_peers = vec!["123.0.0.1", "124.0.0.1"];
    let new_conn_fut = futures::future::join_all(new_peers.iter().map(|peer| {
        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    }));

    // awaits all futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(conn_fut, new_conn_fut).await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=225ca19fad2fe6160f0987591c012bdd)

output:

```
connecting to 127.0.0.1
connecting to 139.48.123.146
connecting to 123.123.46.209
connecting to 123.0.0.1
connecting to 124.0.0.1
processed 127.0.0.1
processed 139.48.123.146
processed 123.123.46.209
processed 123.0.0.1
processed 124.0.0.1
```

But, since I am retrieving the addresses from another asynchronous process I have this:

```
pub async fn process(addr: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
    println!("processed {}", addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["127.0.0.1", "139.48.123.146", "123.123.46.209"];

    let conn_fut = futures::future::join_all(peers.iter().map(|peer| {
        async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    }));
    
    let (tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);
    
    let handle_conn_fut = async move {
        while let Some(peer) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    };
    
    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        for peer in ["123.0.0.1", "124.0.0.1"] {
            tx.send(peer).await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    // does not await futures in parallel
    futures::future::join3(conn_fut, handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d27d6a2dda441dee19563ca7fbdb6f3)

output:

```
connecting to 127.0.0.1
connecting to 139.48.123.146
connecting to 123.123.46.209
connecting to 123.0.0.1
processed 127.0.0.1
processed 139.48.123.146
processed 123.123.46.209
processed 123.0.0.1
connecting to 124.0.0.1
processed 124.0.0.1
```

Which does not process the new peers in parallel. I am not sure how write this, I have looked into using [`futures::stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/index.html) which `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver` can be converted into by using [`tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.9/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.ReceiverStream.html) (?). The `futures::stream::StreamExt` trait implements [`for_each_concurrent`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each_concurrent) which can process each element in parallel.

I am not sure what the best way is to go about this. Intuitively, I want to write something like this:

```rust
async fn connect(peers: futures::stream::Stream<&str>) {
    peers.for_each_concurrent(|p| process(p).await);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let mut initial_peers = vec!["127.0.0.1", "139.48.123.123"];
  let peers = futures::stream::iter(initial_peers)
  let conn_fut = connect(peers)
  let new_peers_fut = async move {
      for new_peer in ["123.0.0.1", "124.0.0.1"] {
          peers.push_back(new_peer)
      }
  }
  futures::future::join(conn_fut, new_peers_fut).await
}
```

Is it possible to process the elements in a `futures::stream::Stream` in parallel and simultaneously append new elements to the end of the stream which in turn are also processed together with the other elements?

Comment: Yes, use a channel. It's not clear what problem you are having while doing so.

Comment: @Shepmaster The problems is that the peers are not processed in parallel. Compare the second output with the third output. `connecting to 124.0.0.1` comes before `processed 124.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by converting `conn_fut` to a `futures::stream` and chained it with `rx`:

```
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

pub async fn process(addr: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
    println!("processed {}", addr);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["127.0.0.1", "139.48.123.146", "123.123.46.209"];
    let peers = futures::stream::iter(peers);

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);

    let rx = tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream::new(rx);
    let rx = peers.chain(rx);
    
    let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0,
        |peer| async move {
            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer).await;
        }
    );
    
    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        for peer in ["123.0.0.1", "124.0.0.1"] {
            tx.send(peer).await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    // awaits all futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;
}
```

output:

```
connecting to 127.0.0.1
connecting to 139.48.123.146
connecting to 123.123.46.209
connecting to 123.0.0.1
connecting to 124.0.0.1
processed 127.0.0.1
processed 139.48.123.146
processed 123.123.46.209
processed 123.0.0.1
processed 124.0.0.1
```

Comment: Putting together a channel, `ReceiverStream`, `.chain()`, and `for_each_concurrent` looks like a pretty sweet combination. You should probably just keep the final solution if it is fully superior to the first solution. Keeping answers clear and succinct will help other viewers that may have a similar problem in the future.